# Empty spaces are being automaticlly added when I write a text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use json library to edit a text file on my PC, the this is what the Text.txt file contains:

```
{"name": "mike", "born": 1998}
```

and this is the code that I'm writing

```
import json

text = """\
{
"look": "avarage",
"income": "high"
}"""
File = open("Test.txt", "r+")
json_from_file = json.load(File)
json_from_text = json.loads(text)
json_from_file.update(json_from_text)
File.truncate(0)
json.dump(json_from_file, File)
File.close()
```

the Text.txt should contain:

```
{"name": "mike", "born": 1998, "look": "avarage", "income": "high"}
```

but instead I get several empty spaces at the beginning (31 in total) that it looks like this

```
                              {"name": "mike", "born": 1998, "look": "avarage", "income": "high"}
```

any idea how I can get rid off it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace truncate with seek:

```
import json

text = """\
{
"look": "avarage",
"income": "high"
}"""
File = open("Test.txt", "r+")
json_from_file = json.load(File)
json_from_text = json.loads(text)
json_from_file.update(json_from_text)
File.seek(0)
json.dump(json_from_file, File)
File.close()
```

`File.truncate` doesn't change the current file position, and since you've already read the file you are at the of it (31 characters in your example).

Keep in mind that if you were the modify the file in a way that would make it shorter, `File.seek` alone will not do, as you might leave undesired characters at the end.